# Rubaxa sortable causes scroll and weird behaviors on some android mobile devices i.e. s4

Tags: jquery, rubaxa-sortable

Using the jquery Sortable Rubaxa, and detected that in some devices is almost impossible to sort a list, causing while sorting a page scroll.

After adding the scroll options the situation improved in some devices as the s5, but no improvement at all on some others.

This are the options that I am using so far.

```
<ul>
  <li id="1" class="listSort">Item 1</li>
  <li id="2" class="listSort">Item 2</li>
  <li id="3" class="listSort">Item 3</li>
  <li id="4" class="listSort">Item 4</li>
  <li id="5" class="listSort">Item 5</li>
  ...
  ...
  <li id="20" class="listSort">Item 22</li>
</ul>


var sortable_settings = {
    handle: '.listSort',
    animation: 0,
    ghostClass: "ghost",
    scroll: true,
    scrollSensitivity: 300,
    scrollSpeed: 5,
    //forceFallback: true,
    //fallbackClass: "draggedGhost",
    //fallbackOnBody: true,
    //fallbackTolerance: 5,

    onMove: function (event) {

        //console.log(evt);
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        setTimeout(function () {
            setItemListPositions(target.id);
        }, 200); // default 200

    }
};
```

As note, after adding the scoll options the user experience improved in ios devices.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Not really, by changing scroll parameters sorting improved in mobiles but stopped working on iPad.